# Ember Data incompatible with Rails JSON response: Encountered a resource with an undefined type

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-model

I'm trying to set up Ember Data to talk to a Rails backend. Ember succeeds at calling the endpoint, gets both a 200 and some response data. The problem is that Ember is unable to match the response data to one of my Ember models I've made.

My model code:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  user_id: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  transcription: DS.attr('string'),
  transcription_time: DS.attr('date'),
  transcription_date: DS.attr('date'),
  recording_url: DS.attr('string'),
  state: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Below is an image of how the backend returns data along with the error from Ember:

[image]

Error: `Encountered a resource with an undefined type.`

I don't need to include `created_at` or `updated_at` in my Ember models do I? Also, how does Ember know to connect `user_id` with my `User` Ember model? Is that what's causing the error? I specified `user_id` to `belongTo('user')` though. Do I need to explicitly include `type` field in my JSON response? This doesn't seem right though.

I've read a couple of Ember guides, including their [guide on models](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/models/) and their [guide on serializers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/models/customizing-serializers/). I don't need to write a custom JSONAPISerializer, do I? Most of the guides I read did not say to do this. Any help and tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON response should include a "type" field, according to the [JSONAPI](http://jsonapi.org/) spec. Here's what the JSON from my rails app looks like:

```
{"data":{"attributes":{"title":"asdf","body":"adsf"},"type":"posts"}}
```

Are you using Active Model Serializers on the rails side, and did you configure it to use the JSONAPI renderer?

All you have to do is set `ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter` in an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/jsonapi.rb
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
```

It should include the `type` field automatically.

If you still have trouble, I think if you share some of your rails code I can help.

Comment: Thank you! I configured my Rails and now it does it automatically too :)